# Is it possible to zoom on the y axis in dc.js?

Tags: d3.js, svg, visualization, dc.js

With bubble charts in dc.js, enabling `mouseZoomable` causes the scroll wheel to only zoom in and out on the x axis. Is it possible to zoom on the y axis as well?

Comment: It is possible to do using d3, so I would recommend exploring how to apply the d3 code to your bubble chart.

Comment: It is definitely doable in d3, but I'm looking for a way to do it without reimplementing dc.js's bubble chart (and their ecosystem, since my charts don't exist in isolation). I went through the dc source and zooming is not at all obvious, so maybe that's what I have to do.

Comment: doesn't look possible with the dc.js api

Comment: @JustinPoehnelt Yeah, I ended up just reimplementing what I wanted. Oh well.

Comment: @jclancy - Did you end up writing a custom zoom handler that supported y-zooming? Any chance you could share your code as a proposed solution?